# How to convert negative number to positive by |= Operator in C#?

Tags: c#

We all know that the highest bit of an Int32 defines its sign. `1` indicates that it's negative and `0` that it's positive (possibly reversed).  Can I convert a negative number to a positive one by changing its highest bit?

I tried to do that using the following code:

```
i |= Int32.MaxValue;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it have to be using |=?  Could you just call Math.Abs()? or negate the number?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are just looking for a bitwise way to do this (like an interview question, etc), you need to negate the number (bitwise) and add 1:

```
int x = -13;
int positiveX = ~x + 1;
```

This will flip the sign if it's positive or negative.  As a small caveat, this will NOT work if x is int.MinValue, though, since the negative range is one more than the positive range.

Of course, in real world code I'd just use `Math.Abs()` as already mentioned...

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: As one would expect, Math.Abs(int.MinValue) doesn't work either. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: You may use Abs if you are trying on decimal. It works! decimal x = -13;
            decimal positiveX = Math.Abs(x);

Answer (score 35):

Why don't you just use the `Math.Abs(yourInt)` method?  I don't see the necessity to use bitwise operations here.

Answer (score 2):

The most-significant bit defines it's sign, true. But that's not everything:

To convert a positive number to a negative one, you have to:

1. Negate the number (for example, +1, which is `0000 0001` in binary, turns into `1111 1110`)
2. Add 1 (`1111 1110` turns into `1111 1111`, which is -1)

That process is known as [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Inverting the process is equally simple:

1. Substract 1 (for example, -1, `1111 1111` turns into `1111 1110`)
2. Negate the number (`1111 1110` turns into `0000 0001`, which is +1 again).

As you can see, this operation is impossible to implement using the *binary or*-operator. You need the *bitwise-not* and *add*/*substract*.

The above examples use 8-bit integers, but the process works exactly the same for all integers. **Floating-point numbers**, however, use only a sign bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about using bitwise operations, it won't work like that. I'm assuming you were thinking you'd flip the highest bit (the sign flag) to get the negative, but it won't work as you expect.

The number 6 is represented as `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110` in a 32-bit signed integer. If you flip the highest bit (the signing bit) to 1, you'll get `10000000 00000000 00000000 00000110`, which is -2147483642 in decimal. Not exactly what you expected, I should imagine. This is because negative numbers are stored in "negative logic", which means that `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` is -1.

If you flip every bit in a positive value `x`, you get `-(x+1)`. For example:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110 = 6
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111001 = -7
```

You've still got to use an addition (or subtraction) to produce the correct result, though.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this by doing:

```
Int a = IntToSolve; //Whatever int you want
b = a < 0 ? a*-1 : a*1 ;
```

Doing this will output only positive ints.
The other way around would be:

```
Int a = IntToSolve; //Same but from positive to negative
b = a < 0 ? a*1 : a*-1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with `Math.Abs(i)` if you want to go from -ve to +ve, or `-1*i` if you want to go both ways?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible with the `|=` operator. It cannot unset bits. And since the sign bit is set on negative numbers you can't unset it.

Answer (score 0):

Your quest is, sadly, futile. The bitwise OR operator will *not* be able to arbitrarily flip a bit. You can *set* a bit, but if that bit is already set, OR will not be able to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely cannot since the negative is [the two's complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of the original one. So even if it is true that in a negative number the MSB is 1 is not enought to put a 1 that bit to obtain the negative. ***You must negate all the bits and add one***.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try simpler way changeTime = changeTime >= 0 ? changeTime : -(changeTime);